# Open URL without showing the browser window using GDK

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an application (developed using GDK) where the glass will open an URL with voice triggered from home screen. The URL actually is just a blank page and its intention is to trigger some process on another PC. The only way that I can find to open an URL is to start an activity with the build-in-browser, for example:

```
String url = "http://www.abc123.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

And I have to swipe down at touchpad to close the browser window once it's loaded. Is there a way to open the URL in background and close the activity once it's loaded (itself) without showing the browser window?
I don't really need the browser window as there is nothing to be shown on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just make a http request?

Here's [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or try Square's [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.abc123.com/");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Note: I haven't test. You can also use AsyncTask or other mechanisms instead of Thread.